# Disk Controller installation failure

Tags: boot, 18.04, dell

I am installing 18.04 on a Dell R420 with a LSI SAS PERC H310 Disk controller. according to [Dell certification](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201211-12067/) This is fully supported in 14.04 but not in 18.04.

Yet when I carry out an install on this server from DVD it sees the disk, creates the partition, copied the files, makes it bootable, etc but on trying to boot the system up after installation it cannot see the disk and says no boot device.

Comment: If it sees the disk, creates partitions, copies files, installs, etc. then it's natively supported. That it can't boot from it later has to do with incorrect BIOS/UEFI settings or with BIOS/UEFI not supporting booting from SAS card.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a try Gabriela, turned out I simply needed to choose the Logical Volume Manager option during installation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for giving it a try Gabriela, turned out I simply needed to choose the Logical Volume Manager option during installation